# Funky playback with Videos

Tags: videos

I'm using the latest 0.5 beta, on really new hardware (ryzen 5 2500U) and when I play videos with Videos (doesn't matter what file format/codec), the playback is all messed up. See: https://youtu.be/JkpX3un7ZW4
I haven't used Linux as a desktop OS for the past 10 years, so I'm not sure which command output would be useful. Please let me know what I should include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue; after a lot of digging around, it turned out to be related to the the `gstreamer1.0-vaapi` package. Removing that package fixed the issue for me.